# Use a function Using-Culture in .TypeText in Powershell

Tags: powershell, formatting, numbers

I want to get the number like `1039,00` (comma is a decimal delimiter).
But now i've got `1039.00`

The thing is in the code:

```
$selection.TypeText("Angebotspreis: Using-Culture de-de {$TotalPrice} Euro ")
```

I've tried to do like this:

```
 $selection.TypeText("Angebotspreis: $(Using-Culture de-de {$TotalPrice}) Euro ")
 $selection.TypeText("Angebotspreis: @"Using-Culture de-de {$TotalPrice}"@ Euro ")
```

and so on.

Using-Culture function is:

```
 Function Using-Culture (
    [System.Globalization.CultureInfo]$culture = (throw “USAGE: Using-Culture -     Culture culture -Script {scriptblock}”),
    [ScriptBlock]$script= (throw “USAGE: Using-Culture -Culture culture -Script {scriptblock}”))
{
    $OldCulture = [System.Threading.Thread]::CurrentThread.CurrentCulture
    trap 
{
    [System.Threading.Thread]::CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = $OldCulture
}
    [System.Threading.Thread]::CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = $culture
    Invoke-Command $script
    [System.Threading.Thread]::CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = $OldCulture
}
```

also, in the console:

```
PS C:\Users\alexz> $(Using-Culture de-de {$TotalPrice})
7908.90
```

but

```
PS C:\Users\alexz> Using-Culture de-de {$TotalPrice}
7908,90
```

How can I fix it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe you are looking for the overloaded `ToString` method on a `double` which you can pass a `f` for Floating point (decimal) values and a `CultureInfo`.

For example:

```
$ammount = 7908.39
$ammount.ToString('f', (New-Object System.Globalization.CultureInfo("de-DE")))
```

**Output:**

```
7908,39
```

---

Or if you want the `€` sign and the dot for the thousends, use `c` for currency:

```
$ammount = 7908.39
$ammount.ToString('c', (New-Object System.Globalization.CultureInfo("de-DE")))
```

**Output:**

```
7.908,39 €
```

Comment: Works like a charm! Thank you a lot!